# 'Disconnected: You are now offline'

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, wired

I am new to Linux and this group as well. So, please let me know if any more information is needed from my side related to the issue I am facing.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04. And I am currently facing an issue with internet connectivity. From past few days, I have read several posts related to connectivity issue and have tried few of the solutions too. But it has not worked so far for me.

Issue:
Wired internet connection is not working for me. I have already tried connecting wifi and its works fine.

Following are some of the details:

Ethernet driver: Marvel Yukon optima 88e8059
Kernel version : tried with 3.16, 3.19, 4.1.1

```
lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Yukon Optima 88E8059 [PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Controller with AVB] [11ab:4381] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c551]
    Kernel driver in use: sky2

sunil@sunil-R480:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:54:7d:68:89  
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:54ff:fe7d:6889/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:244 errors:0 dropped:9 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:18863 (18.8 KB)  TX bytes:39197 (39.1 KB)
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:21281 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21281 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1608791 (1.6 MB)  TX bytes:1608791 (1.6 MB)

sunil@sunil-R480:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Upgrading kernel to 3.19 may help. It can be done by `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid`.

Comment: ok, let me try that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `ifconfig; route -n` when connected by wire.

Comment: The card does not get ip address and drops some packets. That must be a driver issue, if it works in Windows.